# How to create movement similar to terraria?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to write a script for acceleration and deacceleration with a maximum velocity for movement, my game will be similar to terraria and it's being made in C# unity. I'm relatively new to programming so explanations would help a bunch. Also, would it be recommended that I change the values within unity or in the scripts?

Here's what I have so far:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Rigidbody2D rb;
    private SpriteRenderer sprite;
    private Animator anim;

    public float dirX = 0f;
    [SerializeField] private float moveSpeed = 2f;
    [SerializeField] private float jumpSpeed = 4f;

    private void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        sprite = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }
    private void Update()
    {
        dirX = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(dirX * moveSpeed, rb.velocity.y);

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, jumpSpeed);
        }
        
        UpdateAnimation();
    }

//Updates Character animation 
    private void UpdateAnimation()
    {
        if (dirX > 0f)
        {
            anim.SetBool("running", true);
            sprite.flipX = false;
        }
        else if (dirX < 0f)
        {
            anim.SetBool("running", true);
            sprite.flipX = true;
        }
        else
        {
            anim.SetBool("running", false);
        }
    }
}
```

I don't really know where to start so I haven't really tried anything yet.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve an acceleration you need to use the appropriate API in the form of [Rigidbody2D.AddForce](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D.AddForce.html).

For Horizontal movement:

```csharp
rb.AddForce(Vector2.right* dirX * acceleration);//TODO define float acceleration
```

For jumping:

```csharp
rb.AddForce(Vector2.up * jumpspeed, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
```

The simplest way to achieve deceleration aside from the friction you have with the ground (modifiable by using [Physics Material 2D](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-PhysicsMaterial2D.html)) is by setting the `Linear Drag` on your Rigidbody2D component.

You can artificially limit the rigidbody velocity by [clamping it's magnitude](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector2.ClampMagnitude.html) to your desired value at the end of your update loop.

```csharp
rb.velocity = Vector2.ClampMagnitude(rb.velocity, maxVelocity);
```

It is recommended to use [FixedUpdate](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.FixedUpdate.html) instead of the normal Update when you're working with a rigidbody or by adding a deceleration force when the player doesn't give any movement input.

There are more refined methods to achieve better control over the player characters handling. You can find tutorials on this topic.